# How to get the common values among lists in dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a tsv file in the following format:

```
Gene   version   start           end
ADK    1         23,45,67,89     30,51,79,96
ADK    2         23,67,89        30,79,96
ADK    3         23,89           30,96
```

I want to create a dictionary with only the start and ends which are common across all 3 versions for a particular gene. The dictionary should be in the following format:

```
{'ADK':{'start':[23,89], 'end':[30.96]}
```

The code that I am trying till now is:

```
def get_strong_ranges(file):
    for entry in utils.records_iterator(file):
        if entry['gene'] not in gene_exons:
            gene_exons[entry['gene']] = {'start': list(),'end': list()}
        gene_exons[entry['gene']]['start'].append(entry['start'])
        gene_exons[entry['gene']]['end'].append(entry['end'])
```

However, I am yet to sort out the common ones. Any suggestions on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'gene': ['ADK', 'ADK', 'ADK'], 'version': [1,2,3], 'start': [[23,45,67,89], [23,67,89], [23,89]], 'end': [[30,51,79,96], [30,79,96], [30,96]]})

df
Out[14]: 
  gene  version             start               end
0  ADK        1  [23, 45, 67, 89]  [30, 51, 79, 96]
1  ADK        2      [23, 67, 89]      [30, 79, 96]
2  ADK        3          [23, 89]          [30, 96]
```

Convert the start column from lists to numbers:

```
start_df = df.explode('start')
start_df 
Out[16]: 
  gene  version start               end
0  ADK        1    23  [30, 51, 79, 96]
0  ADK        1    45  [30, 51, 79, 96]
0  ADK        1    67  [30, 51, 79, 96]
0  ADK        1    89  [30, 51, 79, 96]
1  ADK        2    23      [30, 79, 96]
1  ADK        2    67      [30, 79, 96]
1  ADK        2    89      [30, 79, 96]
2  ADK        3    23          [30, 96]
2  ADK        3    89          [30, 96]
```

count the number of versions per value of "start":

```
start_df_counts = start_df.groupby(['gene', 'start'])['version'].count()
Out[19]: 
gene  start
ADK   23       3
      45       1
      67       2
      89       3
Name: version, dtype: int64
```

compare it to the number of unique versions:

```
start_df_counts == len(set(start_df['version']))
Out[20]: 
gene  start
ADK   23        True
      45       False
      67       False
      89        True
Name: version, dtype: bool
```

Take only those values:

```
start_df_counts[start_df_counts == len(set(start_df['version']))]
Out[30]: 
gene  start
ADK   23       3
      89       3
Name: version, dtype: int64
```

Now, group by the gene and convert to list:

```
start_df_common = start_df_counts[start_df_counts == len(set(start_df['version']))]
start_df_common = start_df_common.reset_index()
start_df_common.groupby('gene')['start'].apply(list)
Out[35]: 
gene
ADK    [23, 89]
```

and finally, we can convert it to dict:

```
final_start_dict = start_df_common.groupby('gene')['start'].apply(list).to_dict()
final_start_dict
Out[38]: {'ADK': [23, 89]}
```

Now you can apply the same for the end column.

Hope it helps :)